# Numpy meshgrid with multivariate normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to avoid using a double loop in the following piece of code that relies on `np.meshgrid`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def multi_normal(x, mu, covariance):
    d = len(x)
    x_m = x - mu
    return (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)**d * np.linalg.det(covariance))) * np.exp(-(np.linalg.solve(covariance, x_m).T.dot(x_m))/2)

x = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

mean = [[0.], [0.]]
covariance = [
    [1., 0.8], 
    [0.8, 1.]]

# I DO NOT WANT TO USE THIS DOUBLE LOOP, THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        z[i,j] = multi_normal(np.matrix([[xx[0,i]], [yy[j,0]]]), mean, covariance)
        
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

I wa trying to do something like:

```py
z = multi_normal([xx, yy], mean, covariance)
```

but I get array dimensions mismatch errors. It would be great if someone could also offer some explanation as to why this does not work.

Comment: Can you summarize what you are trying to do in one or two sentences?

Comment: replace double loop by a one-liner. My attempt failed as shown above.